# A closed set in $l_2$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

If $n\in\mathbb{N}$, let $e_n=(0,0,...,1,...)\in l_2$, where the $1$ appears in the $n$-th coordinate and $e_0=(0,0,...)$.

If $t\ge 0$ and $t\in [n,n+1]$  let $L(t)=(1-(t-n))e_n+(t-n)e_{n+1}$.

Then I want to prove $A=\{L(t):t\ge 0\}$ is closed in $l_2$.

What I tried is to take a convergent sequence in $A$, say $(L(t_k))$ converges to $y\in l_2$, and prove $y\in A$. It suffices to show $(t_k)$ converges (or has a convergent subsequence) to some $t_0$, because of that $L(t_0)=y$ (by continuity). Since $(L(t_k))$ converges to $y$, I think somehow we could find $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that the sequence $(t_k)_{k\ge N}$ is bounded and we're done. I don't know how to do this, though.

Here are some computes. If $k\in\mathbb{N}$ with $t_k\in [n_k,n_k+1]$ and $y=(y_1,y_2,...)$ then $$\|L(t_k)-y\|_{l_2}^2=\sum_{i=1}^{n_k-1}|y_i|^2+|1-(t_k-n_k)-y_{n_k}|+|t_k-n_k-y_{n_{k+1}}|+\sum_{i=n_k+2}^{\infty}|y_i|^2$$

Of course for every $\epsilon >0$ there is $N_{\epsilon}$ such that $\|L(t_k)-y\|_{l_2}^2<\epsilon$ if $k\ge N_{\epsilon}$. However I don't know how to conclude the boundedness of a tail of $(t_k)$.

Any hint would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $L(t)$ is continuous on $[n,n+1]$ for every $n=0,1,2,3,\dots$ because
$$
         \|L(t)-L(t')\|=\|-(t-t')e_n+(t-t')e_{n+1}\|=\sqrt{2}|t-t'|,\;\;\; n \le t,t' \le n+1.
$$
And $L$ is continuous from the right of $0$ and at every positive integer. It can be shown that $\|L(t)\|^2 \ge 1/2$ for all $t \ge 0$. Furthermore, if $|t-t'| \ge 2$, then $L(t) \perp L(t')$, leading to
$$
        \|L(t)-L(t')\|^2 = \|L(t)\|^2+\|L(t')\|^2 \ge \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}=1.
$$
Therefore, if $\{ L(t_n) \}$ converges to some $y$, it must be that $\{ t_n \}$ all lie within a finite subinterval of $[0,\infty)$. So there is a convergent subsequence $\{ t_{n_k} \}$ with a limit $t_0$. It follows that $L(t_0)=y$, which proves that $L[0,\infty)$ is a closed path.